# java - Gluon: how to stop services in the background?

Tags: java, javafx, location, maps, gluon-mobile

In the app we develop, we have a screen requiring a map - for this we use the GluonMaps-api.

To locate the user location we use the positionservice, which works fine. However, when the screen changes, the positionservice still runs in the background, even though the view is not shown anymore and the service not needed. How can we stop the service?

In the official documentation there is nothing written about it:
http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/4.4.1/index.html?com/gluonhq/charm/down/package-summary.html

Comment: The Position Service is designed both on Android and iOS to stop when the app is [paused](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down/src/11c36e187921b2eac4a3d518cc00ad9108cab89f/plugins/plugin-position/android/src/main/java/com/gluonhq/charm/down/plugins/android/AndroidPositionService.java?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#AndroidPositionService.java-137) and it goes to the background, resuming again when the app resumes. There is no other option for now. Probably some API for starting/stopping the service on demand will be required.

Comment: How would you suggests solving this problem? 
Using native position services (iOS and Android specific) or developing our own API to do it?

Comment: The Charm Down services actually use native services from the mobile devices.You can easily modify the [service](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down) according to your needs, and build a local version. Feel free to raise a PR [here](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down/pull-requests/) if you want to share your changes. Or you can file an [issue](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down/issues?status=new&status=open) as well.

Comment: Thank you José! Since we have other priorities now (like: finishing the app itself), we filed an issue on your given link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new gluon service allows to stop the service:
http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/5.1.0-SNAPSHOT/com/gluonhq/charm/down/plugins/PositionService.html

Make sure that when you upgrade you add the new parameters the way you need it.